# Get message mask of webSocket message

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to implement a rudimentary ACK protocol for websocket. I'm using a node server with [ws library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-client), so I need for the client to send some kind of message ID, and then, from the server, send back a reply with that ID so the client knows that the message has been recieved. I know messages are masked, and maybe I can use the mask as an ID. The question is how can I get the mask? (Or another thing I can use as a msg ID).

I have complete control over the client and the server, so I could eventually do this in the app layer, sending an ID in the msg body, and responding from the server. But first I want to try to do it in a lower level.

Comment: Do it in the app layer. First: that's not the purpose of mask. Secondly: you will find it problematic if proxies are involved. Third: you couple app layer with transport. Which makes it harder if you one day decide to switch transport.

Comment: I still think an ACK protocol should be implemented in the transport layer instead of in the app layer. I really dont know why WS specifications do not mention any ACK since its so easy to do and help a lot.

Comment: Websocket has no use for ack. Why would it be implemented in transport? Ack is meaningless there. Moreover we have no idea what you use this ack for, and how exactly it should work. It literally means that it belongs to app layer.

Comment: Furthermore the websocket protocol mandates every mask to be a random/unpredictable int. So how would your ack message refer to the frame it is actually acknowledging? It cannot reuse the same mask. And therefore the ID has to be moved to app layer. And now you have a very weird situation where IDs are part of transport, but ACK IDs are part of app. This is a mess. Finally the only advantage I can see is that you save those 4 bytes, which is unlikely to matter at all.

Comment: The transport layer is in charge of reliably delivering messages. In other protocols the transport layer has an ACK message, and retransmitt the message in case of a fail. 

Having said that, I finally build an ACK system in the app layer, adding a header in the handshake so the server know we are working with an ACK, and sending every message with a 6 digit number appended. The server recieves the message, slice those charactgers, and send back another message with those characters so the clients know that the message has been recieved.

Comment: The reliability is implemented at the lower level, i.e. http (which itself is supposed to be implemented over reliable channel, e.g. tcp or quic). The websocket protocol is not concerned with that.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it helped me decide wht to do